# Edit and Add in the same view page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a registration form using the codeigniter.

I have successfully completed the inserting part and now i'm trying to update my records using same view page, which i had used for inserting the values in to datbase.

However, I am getting errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: fn
>
> Filename: views/myform.php
>
> Line Number: 18

Can any one help me in fixing this issue?

I am not able to fetch the values in the form.

Controller:

```
    public function updatedata($id)
    {
      //$id=$this->input->get('id');
      $result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);

          $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
              $this->load->view('myform',$result);
          } 

          else 
          {
              $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
              $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
              $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                  $fn=$this->input->post('fname');
                  $ln=$this->input->post('lname');
                  $un=$this->input->post('username');
                  $em=$this->input->post('email');
                  if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
                       {
                           $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name');
                           $file = ("uploads/".$result['data'][0]->filename);
                            //delete the existing file if needed
                            if (file_exists($file)) {
                                unlink($file);
                            }
                       }
                  else
                       {
                          $fi= $result['data'][0]->filename;
                       }
                  $this->Form_model->updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id);
                  echo 'Successfully updated your record';
                  //exit();
              } 
    }
```

model

```
    //get values 
        function displayrecordsById($id)
    {
            $query=$this->db->query("select * from form where ID='".$id."'");
            return $query->result();
    }

        //update record
        function updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id)
    {
            $query=$this->db->query("update form SET first_name='$fn',last_name='$ln',username='$un',email='$em',filename='$fi' where ID='".$id."'");
    }
```

view

```
    <body>

        <?php echo form_open_multipart('form'); ?>
            <div class="container">

                <h2 style="color:#ff1a1a">Registration Form</h2><br>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">First Name</h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="<?php echo set_value("first_name", $fn); ?>" size="50">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("fname");?></span>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Last Name</h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="<?php echo set_value("last_name", $ln); ?>" size="50">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("lname");?></span>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Username</h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value("username", $un); ?>" size="50">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("username");?></span>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Email Address</h5>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value("email", $em); ?>" size="50">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("email");?></span>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Password</h5>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" size="50">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("password");?></span>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Password Confirm</h5>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passconf" value="" size="50">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("passconf");?></span><br>

                <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Upload image</h5>
                <input type="file" name="filename" size="20">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/' . $row->filename);?>" class="img-responsive" alt="image" width="100px" height="100px"><br><input type="file" name="filename" value="">
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("filename");?></span><br>

                <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"></div>

            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view use $fn like:

```
`$data[0]->$fn`
```

This is because result['***data***'] is what your are passing to the view. Your data comes from your model as an array but since your querying by Id you can use [0] in this situation. Assuming your Ids are unique.

If you have a many different records per Id you will have to use a foreach loop to get all of them.

You will have to do this with $fn, $ln etc..

Also you should read this: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html

Your queries are not safe if they are going to be handling user input data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one set of data to pass to view, i.e only one set like this:

```
$result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);
```

You can change array to :

```
$data=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);
```

and pass like this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
 $this->load->view('myform',$data);
}
```

Then You will be able to access value directly in view using the **$fn** name.